# How to reverse the order of a match function, from top-bottom to the activecell-top

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have the following in cell T124

```
=MATCH("Sub-Assembly",M1:M124,0)
```

I would like to search from the active row (124) upwards in a specified column (M) and return the first cell's path that has the value Sub-Assembly within.

Currently, it looks in ascending order from row 1 and returns the first value, I would like it to look upwards from the active row.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you'd need an UDF

Comment: @Fernando J. Rivera What is a UDF?

Comment: It's a "User Defined Function", essentially a VBA Macro that you program to do what you need.  Although it does seem you can do this specific question without a UDF (and just use built in functions) after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try,

```
=aggregate(14, 6, row($1:$124)/(M$1:M$124="Sub-Assembly"), 1)
```

Comment: Do you have a VBA equivalent?  I have managed to do most of it with the exception of the row function. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use this, enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

```
=MAX(IF(M1:M124="Sub-Assembly",1,0)*ROW(M1:M124),0)
```

Comment: Do you have a VBA version of this?

Answer (score 2):

You can adapt `MATCH` function for this, e.g.

`=MATCH(2,1/(M$1:M$124="Sub-Assembly"))`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

like `MATCH` this will return the position within the range, but of last match, not first

Comment: @pnuts Do you have a VBA version of this?

Comment: @barry Houdini Please see above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this my using an Array Equation

```
=MAX(IF(M1:M124="Sub-Assembly",ROW(M1:M124)-ROW(INDEX(M1:M124,1,1))+1))
```

Click in the formula bar after and type ctrl+shift+enter.